# UI thread and Surfaceview

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface

I am very new on android. I saw in the android developer website two rules about android threading :

```
1 : Do not block the UI thread
2 : Do not access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread
```

If you look at the LunarLander Sample of android sdk, you can see this code :

```
class LunarView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

//...

public LunarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

      class LunarThread extends Thread {

         //...

         private void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                //do some drawing on the canvas
         }
      }

      //...

    public LunarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        // ...

        // create thread only; it's started in surfaceCreated()
        thread = new LunarThread(holder, context, new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message m) {
                mStatusText.setVisibility(m.getData().getInt("viz"));
                mStatusText.setText(m.getData().getString("text"));
            }
        });

        //...

     }


     //...

  }
```

As you can see we are creating a new thread who is rendering the view.

Why this code doesn't violate the 2nd rule of the android framework's threading ?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never tried this code before. But I guess `handleMessage(Message m)` is executed in main(UI) thread. For verifying it, you can add some code to check.

```
thread = new LunarThread(holder, context, new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message m) {
                if (Thread.currentThread().getId() == 1) {
                    // main thread
                }
                else {
                    // other thread
                }
                mStatusText.setVisibility(m.getData().getInt("viz"));
                mStatusText.setText(m.getData().getString("text"));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The thread is not rendering the view. I'm not completely sure of how it works but it uses the handler to send messages to the thread that owns the view. LunarLander manages the threads the same way as this example: https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

Comment: You ARE allowed to render in another thread. This is the entire point of the example : create a second thread which writes to the canvas which is *later* transferred to the MainUI.